# How can I use the same function template to save 3 different arrays to 3 different files?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, file-io

How can I use the same function template to save 3 different arrays to 3 different files? (one array per file)

The array types are `int`, `float`, and `char`

The closest I've gotten is the following code:

```
template <typename T>
    void saveToTextFile(T *arr, const int size)
    {
    ofstream outFile("arraytextfile.txt", ios::out);`

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
            outFile << arr[i] << ' ';
        }// end for

        outFile << endl;

        outFile.close();
    }
```

This, of course, creates a new text file the first time it is called, then truncates the file when opened again.  **I need to call this template 3 different times and have it save data to a new file each time. Each file should contain a different array.**

Comment: Is passing the name of the file to create, as an additional parameter to this function, too obvious of a solution?

Comment: That is exactly the solution I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you pass the `filePath` via parameter, using a `pointer`

```
 void saveToTextFile(T *arr, const int size, const char *outputFilePath) {
     ofstream outFile(outputFilePath , ios::out);`
 }
```

you'd pass the `filePath` to your function like:

```
const char * location = "a/c/d.text".c_str();
saveToTextFile(arr, 5, location) // or for short 
saveToTextFile(arr, 5,"a/c/d.text".c_str())
```

Comment: `"a/c/d.text".c_str();` got a bug here. `"a/c/d.text"` is a `const char` array, not a `std::string`, so not only is there no `c_str()` to call, there is no reason to call anything. The conversion to a `const char *` comes free of charge.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that you're calling this function with only three different types, and you're using at least C++11, a simple (but not really elegant)  solution is use type traits and check the type; something like

```
std::ofstream outFile(
   std::is_same<T, char>::value
      ? "file-char.txt"
      : (std::is_same<T, int>::value
         ? "file-int.txt"
         : "file-double.txt"), std::ios::out);
```

If you cant use C++11 or newer, you can simulate `std::is_same` with something as follows

```
template <typename, typename>
struct isSame
 { static const bool value = false; };

template <typename T>
struct isSame<T, T>
 { static const bool value = true; };
```

But for a more generic solution, you can use `typeid()`; by example

```
std::string  fName = "file-";

fName += typeid(*arr).name();
fName += ".txt";

std::ofstream outFile(fName, std::ios::out);
```

but take in count that the `typeid()` give a `name()` that is implementation dependent.